# Upgrade of Ubuntu components without Internet connection

Tags: apt, package-management, python, java, nginx

We want to update following items on Ubuntu. But our server is not connected to Internet due to security reason. What alternatives do we have?

1. Python & python 3
2. NodeJS
3. PHP
4. Python Computer vision (openCV)
5. MongoDB
6. Nginx
7. Loopback
8. Tensorflow
9. Theano
10. Java
11. Zebra crossing
12. Highlighter component dependencies
13. Barcode reader dependencies
14. NodeJS packages
15. Python packages

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?